# How to find coordinates of the points A, B of a sphere with screen coordinates?

Tags: computational-geometry

I put my question at here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503745/how-can-i-get-correct-the-point-a-and-b-automatically-in-this-picture/503838?noredirect=1#comment1272706_503838 to find the way draw the points `A` and `B` automatically. This points lie on the circle is intersection of the sphere `x^2 + y^2 + (z-3)^2 = 25` and the plane `z = 0.` How to find coordinates of the points A, B of a sphere with screen coordinates?

Comment: You can use `AffineTransform`s to do the orthographic projection from 3D to 2D, for inspiration look e.g. in the basic examples section of the [`ViewMatrix` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewMatrix.html). If you use this to transform a Circle described as an `ImplicitRegion` i'm sure you can analytically solve this.

Comment: Is this a math question or a question about the software Wolfram Mathematica?